# Is it possible to determine if a string begins with an character repeating x times?

Tags: python, string

I have a two strings

```
code_one = "222abc"
code_two = "2abc"
```

Is there a way I can determine that strings begin with "2" repeating any number of times?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use `lstrip()` and compare the lengths:

```
>>> code_one = "222abc"
>>> len(code_one) - len(code_one.lstrip("2"))
3
```

Or if you just want to check the string starts with some characters:

```
>>> code_one.startswith("222")
True
```

Comment: Beautiful! - Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming tests would include characters other than '2', perhaps grab character [0] and compare to [1] and if equal then lstrip on that character as shown to get a count (if needed )